# compared date in laravel query

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I wont to sort data from table post but if date are equal
exemple :
id name date
1   a   2020/10/10
2   b   2020/10/10
3   c   2020/11/20
this is my query

```
->whereDate('date','=',$post->date)
```

Comment: try it with ->where('date','=',$post->date) . Are you shure that 'date' is the right column? date or created_at

Comment: yes it is the right column